# How can I run different build configurations with different output paths in the IIS Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-applications, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

In my Web Application I have 3 different build configuriations:

- Debug
- Release
- Demo

My Web Application will be copied into three different folders depending on these three configurations:

[image]

In my output path I get the following 3 folders: C:\Projects\MyWebApp\

[image]

Now I can call these 3 folders via the IIS Express, when I use subdomains. I have added these lines to my *applicationhost.config*:

[image]

Now I am able to access my 3 different folders via 3 different subdomains in the browser:

- http://debug.localhost:62238
- http://release.localhost:62238
- http://demo.localhost:62238

**My Problem:**

How can I teach Visual Studio 2013 to use the url of the current choosen configuration? I tried the following:

[image]

Unfortunately Visual Studio is not able to process environment variables in this field.